# Infra for building a browser using chromium

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

Our team has to do a POC of building a browser using chromium with added security posture as per our requirement. The POC was done on a local machine

The POC was successful and now we need to identify how to build an infra to support development of this. The chromium code base is huge and so we felt like having it committed to our repo doesn't make sense. May be the packages which would enforce our security controls for the browser we will build, only that we should maintain and have a mechanism to merge the chromium code base along with our package to generate exe is the right mechanism.

Posting this question to get advice on how we should go about building the infra for codebase and build/run mechanism. The codebase of chromium is huge with frequent release and builds can take hours.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Google use Goma server for distributed compilation as Chromium is a very big project and will take hours to compile even on a high end machine. Also, Chromium changes a lot so most likely you will have maintain your Chromium fork

Comment: @Asesh - Can you please elaborate more on the fork part. I can create a fork but how should I go about making changes so that whenever I pull latest of chromium, there are no conflicts

Comment: If there are changes then there will be conflicts, like I said before, Chromium changes a lot and with almost every versions you will have to either adapt to changes or spend time fixing merge conflicts. I doubt there's an automated way to do so.